# Looking for print_r or var_dump equiv for channel:entries row

Tags: php, debugging

I'm new to expressionengine, and am looking to understand the channel:entries loop better. In the interest of that, I've been looking for something that allows me to print_r or var_dump a channel:entries structure as a whole, and a given row of that structure, like:

```
// Note that this is certainly not correct ee syntax, but rather a plain php representation of what I'm trying to do:
$results = {channel:entries};
print_r($results); // Show members of the channel:entries tag.

foreach ($results as $row) {
    print_r($row); // Show members of a single row of the result set.
}
```

Clarification: in no way am I attempting to output any of this information to a page -- this is merely an attempt to better understand the data contained in a row, so I can make better use of this project I've inherited.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I understand what you're asking, but it doesn't primarily make sense in context to a Channel Entries loop and the EE Template Parsing engine. However, I believe you really are looking for something like this:

```
{!--
This is my template
It has PHP Parsing set to `Output`
--}

<!-- This is our Channel Entries loop, outputting the last 10 entries -->
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}

    <h1>
        <!-- Output this entry's title -->
        {title}
    </h1>

    <?php
    // Hrmmm.. what do we have here?
    var_dump("{title}");
    ?>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you really gotta do things the way you're asking, you can, but it's seriously pointless and overkill (If you're developing for someone, and they don't let your EE Member view channel fields groups [which will tell you your exact information for that channel, minus the default info that goes with every channel entry], friggin' quit. They are awful).

If you really need more information, go to the EE docs and browse, but the only other answer is to use MySQL to query the database for a channel entries information. And in that case, why use EE at all if you're going to write your own queries?

**Edit**

Dude, it's all here:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting there -- what I'm trying to do is not to output final product, but to better understand the data structures of a channel:entries row. I wouldn't put such things into production code, but rather a baseline understanding of what the data includes.

Comment: @KyleJBertelsen Updated my answer.

Comment: @KyleJBertelsen did you end up checking the docs? They really give you the information your looking for. I can help and give you a schema breakdown if you think that'll get this answer in order.

Comment: Thanks. All is good. I'm a little too busy to post-mortem this at the moment, but I'll write-up a definitive answer as soon as I can. Thanks for your help. The short of it was that what I was looking for was the API and database querying.

Comment: Okay, so -- in restrospect, what I was really looking for was the anatomy of an entry in an {exp:channel:entries} loop.

For instance, we all know that {title} exists there, and {url}, but I was looking for a somewhat definitive list of the other variables that are available within that loop. I'm still looking for that list, but I'm gradually becoming more comfortable inside that loop.

Comment: Dude, please read the docs, **it's all there** https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#single-variables , https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#variable-pairs